# Cross product of two lists

Tags: .net, f#

*Messing around with 'extension functions' for the List module. 
(I spent quite a while developing 'mapfold' - which threads an accumulator like fold, but uses it as a parameter to create new values like map - then discovered that that is what `List.scan_left` does)*

For generation of test data, I needed to do a cross product of two lists, This is what I came up with:

```
///Perform cross product of two lists, return tuple
let crossproduct l1 l2 =
    let product lst v2 = List.map (fun v1 -> (v1, v2)) lst
    List.map_concat (product l1) l2
```

Is this any good, or is there already some better way to do this?

Same question for this one:

```
///Perform cross product of three lists, return tuple
let crossproduct3 l1 l2 l3 =
    let tuplelist = crossproduct l1 l2 //not sure this is the best way...
    let product3 lst2 v3 = List.map (fun (v1, v2) -> (v1, v2, v3)) lst2
    List.map_concat (product3 tuplelist) l3
```

Comment: See related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935996/calculating-the-cartesian-product-of-a-list-of-numbers-with-f

Answer (score 27, accepted):

another option is to use F# "sequence expressions" and write something like this:

```
let crossproduct l1 l2 =
  seq { for el1 in l1 do
          for el2 in l2 do
            yield el1, el2 };;
```

(actually, it is almost the same thing as what you wrote, because 'for .. in .. do' in sequence expression can be viewed as map_concat). This works with (lazy) sequences, but if you want to work with lists, you'd just wrap the code inside [ ... ] rather than inside seq { ... }.

Comment: And written like that, crossproduct3 becomes trivial

Answer (score 8):

As of F# 4.0, you can use [`List.allPairs`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-listmodule.html#allPairs) to give the Cartesian product of two lists.

If you have more than two lists, see [How do I compute the cartesian product of n sequences in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334429/how-do-i-compute-the-cartesian-product-of-n-sequences-in-f/50306962#50306962)

Answer (score 5):

Just came across a rather elegant solution to this using computation expressions:

```
type Product () =
  member this.Bind (l,f) = List.collect f l    
  member this.Return n = [n]

let enumeratedPizzas = 
  Product() {
    let! x = ["New York";"Chicago"]
    let! y = ["Pepperoni";"Sausage"]
    let! z = ["Cheese";"Double Cheese"]
    return x,y,z
  }
```

By [Techneilogy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388553/techneilogy), copied from [fssnip.net](http://fssnip.net/4L), follow the link to see commented code.

Comment: I came across this, rather ancient, question - it is worth noting that this is _exactly_ the same pattern as what sequence expressions use, just with a bit uglier syntax. I wrote (a lot) more about the different syntactic options in http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~tp322/drafts/notations.html

Answer (score 1):

Your crossproduct function looks good (you've probably noticed the missing "in" keywords). I like this version of crossproduct3 better, but that's just me :

```
let crossproduct3 l1 l2 l3 = 
List.map_concat 
(fun z ->
 (List.map_concat (fun y -> List.map (fun x -> (x, y, z)) l3) l2)) l1;;
```

Your function has an equivalent algorithmic complexity.

Finally, when using crossproduct on an explicitly *empty* list, you may hit on the *[value restriction](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.fsharp.general/264)* (roughly, a restriction that makes sure the compiler only infers polymorphic types for a syntactic value), that is particularly strict in F#. The solution is to annotate calls that use an empty list, in the following way (if you want the second list to be composed of integers):

```
(crossproduct [3; 4] [] : (int * int) list)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using Benjol answer for a while until I found that you can pretty much do the same thing with `Linq`. Benjol's solution is probably still the most elegant but if anyone wants a solution that you can use with `C#` also then here you go:

```
query {
  for i in [1, 2] do
  for j in [3, 4] do
  select (i, j)
}
```

Which is almost exactly the same as Tomas Petricek's solution except the solution doesn't need to be nested `for` loops so it is slightly simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed something similar - I had to zip a list of sequences to a sequence of lists - so `[(a1,a2,a3,...);(b1,b2,b3,...);(c1,c2,c3,...)] -> ([a1;b1;c1], [a2;b2;c3], ...)`

The following code will do this:

```
   let rec listZip (sl : 'a seq list) =   
       seq {  
           match sl with  
           | [] -> yield []  
           | hd::tl ->  
              for h in hd do  
              for t in listZip tl do  
              yield (h::t)  
   }
```