# Calculating the Cartesian product of a list of numbers with F#

Tags: f#

I am new to f#

I am try to calculate the Cartesian products of a list of numbers. I "borrowed" this.

```
let xs = [1..99]
let ys = [1..99]
seq {for x in xs do for y in ys do yield x * y}
```

Is there a better or more elegant way?

Gary

Comment: Related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482866/f-cross-product-of-two-lists

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another possibiltiy to tackle the problem based on functionality provided by the List module would be:

```
let xs = [1..99]
let ys = [1..99]
let zs = xs |> List.collect (fun x -> ys |> List.map (fun y -> x*y))
```

which avoids the extra calls to .concat and should also do the job.

But I'd stick with your solution. It should be the most readable which is a real matchwinner. (Just try to read the codes out loud. Yours is perfectly understandable and Noldorins or mine are not.)

Comment: Ah, I was wondering where the `mapconcat` method went! It seems it was just renamed to `collect` in the newest version.

Comment: Regarding how understandable/readable of each of our solutions is, I think this is somewhat subjective. We have certainly provided more typically "functional" style solutions, whereas the OP suggested a (perfectly good) solution that uses typically "imperative" constructs. I suspect someone from a functional background would find either of our methods clearer.

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: I don't have a machine with the current F# installed, so I can't test my code. Basically, though, if you steal `sequence` from Haskell, you can write your program as

```
let cartesian = sequence >> List.map product
```

and run it as

```
cartesian [[1..99]; [1..99]]
```

Here's how to write `sequence`. It's a generalised version of the sequence expression you wrote. It just handles an unlimited number of lists: `{ for x in xs do for y in ys do for z in zs ...  yield [x;y;z;...] }`.

```
let rec sequence = function
  | [] -> Seq.singleton []
  | (l::ls) -> seq { for x in l do for xs in sequence ls do yield (x::xs) }
// also you'll need product to do the multiplication
let product = Seq.fold_left1 ( * )
```

Then you can write your program as

```
let cartesian xs ys = [xs; ys] |> sequence |> List.map product
// ... or one-argument, point-free style:
let cartesian' = sequence >> Seq.map product
```

You might have to change some `Seq`s to `List`s.

However, the number of people who can guess the meaning of your non-general list comprehension is probably a lot more than will recognise the name `sequence`, so you're probably better off with the list comprehension. `sequence` comes in handy any time you want to run a whole list of computation expressions, though.

Comment: You'll notice I avoided saying "monad". "Computation expression" still isn't as friendly as "warm fuzzy thing", though. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a slightly more elegant way (at least in the functional sense) to calculate the Cartesian products, which uses the functions that exist within the `List` class. (There's no need to involve sequences or loops here, at least not directly.)

Try this:

```
let xs = [1..99]
let ys = [1..99]
xs |> List.map(fun x -> ys |> List.map(fun y -> x * y)) |> List.concat
```

Slightly longer admittedly, though more functional in style, it would seem.

Comment: Actually the code in the question is closer to a list comprehension than your code, in my opinion. Yours is more like the desugared version of a list comprehension.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean list comprehensions actually - I'm not sure there's a special name for it, but I meant the List.* functions.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "there is no need to involve sequences",  I don't understand what the benefits are of using List.map over Seq.map?

Comment: @thinkhard: The Seq type in F# is actually just an alias for IEnumerable<T> in .NET, with a few additional functions (e.g. `map`). By using `Seq.map`, you're actually iterating over the list as you would using an `IEnumerable`, whereas when using `List.map` you're treating it specifically like as a linked list, thus not adding the overhead (and indirection) of iterables.