# How do I have multiple generators for list comprehensions in F#?

Tags: f#

I am trying to write something like this

```
[(x,y)|x<- [1,2,3], y <- [’a’,’b’]]
 => [(1,’a’),(1,’b’),(2,’a’),(2,’b’),(3,’a’),(3,’b’)]
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935996/calculating-the-cartesian-product-of-a-list-of-numbers-with-f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[for x in [1;2;3] do
 for y in ['a';'b'] do
 yield x,y]
```

Answer (score 1):

just  another fun way

```
[1;2;3] |> List.map ( fun X -> ['a';'b'] |> List.map (fun A -> X,A) )
```

Comment: Or rather `[1;2;3] |> List.collect ( fun X -> ['a';'b'] |> List.map (fun A -> X,A) )`

Comment: @Ed'ka yes, it's must be better.

Answer (score -2):

F# equivalent.

```
List.zip [1;2;3] ['a';'b';'c']
```

Comment: Not quite - this pairs up elements in corresponding positions (and therefore requires lists of the same length); the question is looking for the Cartesian product of the two lists.

Comment: @kvb - Thanks for pointing out. I need to be more careful about comprehending question next time.