# Projecting a list of lists efficiently in F#

Tags: performance, list, f#

I have to do projection of a list of lists which returns all combinations with each element from each list. For example:

```
projection([[1]; [2; 3]]) = [[1; 2]; [1; 3]].
projection([[1]; [2; 3]; [4; 5]]) = [[1; 2; 4]; [1; 2; 5]; [1; 3; 4]; [1; 3; 5]].
```

I come up with a function:

```
let projection lss0 =
    let rec projectionUtil lss accs =
        match lss with
        | []        ->  accs
        | ls::lss'  ->  projectionUtil lss' (List.fold (fun accs' l -> 
                                                        accs' @ List.map (fun acc -> acc @ [l]) accs) 
                                                        [] ls)
match lss0 with
| [] -> []
| ls::lss' ->         
    projectionUtil lss' (List.map (fun l -> [l]) ls)
```

and a testcase:

```
#time "on";;
let N = 10
let fss0 = List.init N (fun i -> List.init (i+1) (fun j -> j+i*i+i));;
let fss1 = projection fss0;;
```

The function is quite slow now, with `N = 10` it takes more than 10 seconds to complete. Moreover, I think the solution is unnatural because I have to breakdown the same list in two different ways. **Any suggestion how I can improve performance and readability of the function?**

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482866/f-cross-product-of-two-lists, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482866/f-cross-product-of-two-lists, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935996/calculating-the-cartesian-product-of-a-list-of-numbers-with-f, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334429/how-do-i-compute-the-cartesian-product-of-n-sequences-in-f

Comment: Basically, any of the top search results for [F# cross product](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=f%23+cross+product) and [F# cartesian](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=f%23+cartesian)...

Comment: For comparison, here's my Scheme version of Cartesian product: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546552/scheme-recursive-function-to-compute-all-possible-combinations-of-some-lists/5546880#5546880

Comment: What you describe is known as the *Cartesian product* of the lists. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334429/how-do-i-compute-the-cartesian-product-of-n-sequences-in-f

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, try to avoid list concatenation (@) whenever possible, since it's O(N) instead of O(1) prepend.

I'd start with a (relatively) easy to follow plan of how to compute the cartesian outer product of lists.

- Prepend each element of the first list to each sublist in the cartesian product of the remaining lists.
- Take care of the base case.

First version:

```
let rec cartesian = function
  | [] -> [[]]
  | L::Ls -> [for C in cartesian Ls do yield! [for x in L do yield x::C]]
```

This is the direct translation of the sentences above to code.

Now speed this up: instead of list comprehensions, use list concatenations and maps:

```
let rec cartesian2 = function
  | [] -> [[]]
  | L::Ls -> cartesian2 Ls |> List.collect (fun C -> L |> List.map (fun x->x::C))
```

This can be made faster still by computing the lists on demand via a sequence:

```
let rec cartesian3 = function
  | [] -> Seq.singleton []
  | L::Ls -> cartesian3 Ls |> Seq.collect (fun C -> L |> Seq.map (fun x->x::C))
```

This last form is what I use myself, since I most often just need to iterate over the results instead of having them all at once.

Some benchmarks on my machine:
Test code:

```
let test f N = 
  let fss0 = List.init N (fun i -> List.init (i+1) (fun j -> j+i*i+i))
  f fss0 |> Seq.length
```

Results in FSI:

```
> test projection 10;;
Real: 00:00:18.066, CPU: 00:00:18.062, GC gen0: 168, gen1: 157, gen2: 7
val it : int = 3628800
> test cartesian 10;;
Real: 00:00:19.822, CPU: 00:00:19.828, GC gen0: 244, gen1: 121, gen2: 3
val it : int = 3628800
> test cartesian2 10;;
Real: 00:00:09.247, CPU: 00:00:09.250, GC gen0: 94, gen1: 52, gen2: 2
val it : int = 3628800
> test cartesian3 10;;
Real: 00:00:04.254, CPU: 00:00:04.250, GC gen0: 359, gen1: 1, gen2: 0
val it : int = 3628800
```

Comment: Excellent answer, I can see the flow of thinking and how you come up with the efficient solution.

Comment: I would suggest to make a tail recursive version too.

Comment: @Ankur: look at Ed'ka's answer for a version that won't kill the stack. Implementing my version in a tail-recursive way will probably involve lots of continuations and headaches, and won't perform well.

Comment: I believe these solutions are all wrong: the cartesian product of an empty list of list is an empty list, not a list of a single empty list.

Answer (score 5):

This function is Haskell's [sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad.html#sequence) (although `sequence` is more generic). Translating to F#:

```
let sequence lss =
    let k l ls = [ for x in l do for xs in ls -> x::xs ]
    List.foldBack k lss [[]]
```

in interactive:

```
> test projection 10;;
Real: 00:00:12.240, CPU: 00:00:12.807, GC gen0: 163, gen1: 155, gen2: 4
val it : int = 3628800
> test sequence 10;;
Real: 00:00:06.038, CPU: 00:00:06.021, GC gen0: 75, gen1: 74, gen2: 0
val it : int = 3628800
```

General idea: avoid explicit recursion in favor to standard combinators (fold, map etc.)

Comment: +1 for foldBack. I somehow never think of traversing lists in F# backwards because of their head::tail structure. But this version won't nuke the stack.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tail-recursive version. It's not as fast as some of the other solutions (only 25% faster than your original function), but memory usage is constant, so it works for extremely large result sets.

```
let cartesian l = 
  let rec aux f = function
    | [] -> f (Seq.singleton [])
    | h::t -> aux (fun acc -> f (Seq.collect (fun x -> (Seq.map (fun y -> y::x) h)) acc)) t
  aux id l
```

Answer (score 1):

You implementation is slow because of the @ (i.e List concat) operation, which is a slow operation and it is being done many a times in recursive way. The reason for @ being slow is that List are Linked list in functional programming and to concat 2 list you have to first go till the end of the list (one by one traversing through elements) and then append another list .

Please look at the suggested references in comments. I hope those will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The following version is even faster than [`cartesian3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6199163/153612), and uses basic features of functional programming (no fancy `List.collect`, `Seq.collect`...)

```
let cartesian xss =
    let rec add x yss s =
        match yss with
        | [] -> s
        | ys :: yss' -> add x yss' ((x :: ys) :: s)

    let rec mul xs yss p =
        match xs with
        | [] -> p
        | x :: xs' -> mul xs' yss (add x yss p)

    let rec cartesian xss c =
        match xss with
        | [] -> c
        | xs :: xss' -> cartesian xss' (mul xs c [])

    cartesian xss [ [] ]
```

Results

```
> test cartesian3 10;;
Real: 00:00:04.132, CPU: 00:00:04.109, GC Gen0: 482, Gen1: 2, Gen2: 1
val it: int = 3628800

> test cartesian 10;;
Real: 00:00:01.414, CPU: 00:00:01.406, GC Gen0: 27, Gen1: 16, Gen2: 2
val it: int = 3628800

> test cartesian3 11;;
Real: 00:00:45.652, CPU: 00:00:45.281, GC Gen0: 5299, Gen1: 5, Gen2: 1
val it: int = 39916800

> test cartesian 11;;
Real: 00:00:17.242, CPU: 00:00:16.812, GC Gen0: 260, Gen1: 174, Gen2: 6
val it: int = 39916800
```

The partition strategy used here is naive: the input list `xss` is separated into head and tail, I believe that a smarter strategy can give much better performance.

*Edit:* Another solution is of *Christopher Strachey*, which is explained in [1] (the observation is that the recursion on list can be expressed by folding):

```
let cartesianf xss =
    let f xs yss =
        let h x ys uss = (x :: ys) :: uss
        let g yss x zss = List.foldBack (h x) yss zss
        List.foldBack (g yss) xs []

    List.foldBack f xss [ [] ]
```

[1] *Mike Spivey. Strachey's function pearl, forty years on.*

Answer (score 0):

```
let crossProduct listA listB listC listD listE = 
  listA |> Seq.collect (fun a -> 
  listB |> Seq.collect (fun b -> 
  listC |> Seq.collect (fun c -> 
  listD |> Seq.collect (fun d -> 
  listE |> Seq.map (fun e -> a,b,c,d,e))
```