# On algorithm of iterating an array of arrays

Tags: algorithm, permutation

there are `n` arrays `a_0, ..., a_n-1`, each of `l` elements. how to write efficient code to iterate all combinations, in which each element is picked from a distinct array. for example, if two arrays are [0, 1]  and [3, 4], then the output should be

```
[0, 3]
[0, 4]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
```

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: So do the values always hold their index position? That is, in the above example, the following are not possible combinations: [0,1], [3,1], [4,3], etc.?

Comment: @Janathan M [0,1], is not a elegible combination, since element 0 and 1 are both from array 0...

Comment: @Richard: ...and [3,0] is not eligible either because 3 comes from the 2nd array, and 0 from the first, right?

Comment: @Janathan it's eligible and that's what is wanted, the elements from different arrays.

Comment: Edited to show all possible permutations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compute the cartesian product of n sequences in F#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334429/how-do-i-compute-the-cartesian-product-of-n-sequences-in-f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do better than `O(l^n)`, as nightcracker correctly points out. Here's one way that you can approach the problem.

Make a large array `A` whose `i`th entry is the array `a_i`, i.e.

`A[i] = a_i`

Now iterate through all words of length `n` on the alphabet `{0,1,...,l}`:

```
-(array*)nextWord:(array*)word {
    array *newWord = word;
    for (int i=n-1; i=>0; ++i) {
        if (word[i] < l) {
            newWord[i] = word[i]+1;
            for (int j=i+1; j<n; ++j) {
                newWord[i] = 0;
            }
            return newWord;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Finally, select the entries based on the word by

```
word = [0, 0, ... , 0];
while (word != NULL) {
    A[0][word[0]], A[1][word[1]], ... , A[n-1][word[n-1]];
    word = nextWord(word);
}
```

Sorry for the inconsistencies in the pseudocode, but hopefully you can discern the logic here.

---

Incidentally, based on the example in the question, I am assuming that the first entry should come from the first array, the second entry from the second array, and so on. If this is not the case, then you can still use the idea above and then permute the entries. However, doing this may lead to repetitions if and only if two of the arrays have a common entry.

Answer (score 3):

In an ideal mathematical environment there is no better algorithm then O(l^n), you are going to produce an output of l^n elements anyway.

If you give us context like programming language or architecture we can think of the algorithm closest to O(l^n).

Comment: puesudo code only,,, actually I thought about using stack to iterate, but still working on it...